# SSRS;provide parameter selection but defaulto to showing report upon opening

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, reportbuilder3.0

A unique request from customer...they would like have the report parameterized where they can select a date from a dropdown, but when they open the report, they do not want to select anything from the parameter dropdown; i.e, they want the report to open and already show the data for the most recent date by default, then if they are interested in seeing a date from the past, only then do they want to use the parameter and select a date. Is it even possible to be able to provide both capabilities?  if so, how? I can just create two separate reports for the user, i.e, one defaulting to the most recent date, and another one that is parameter driven, but trying to avoid this.

I defaulted the report to show the maximum date and keep the parameter, but it always opens empty and prompts me to select a value in the parameter dropdown

Comment: [Some possible answers from this discussion on MS Power BI forum.](https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Report-Server/Date-Parameter-default-issue-in-Report-Builder/m-p/1871177)

Comment: Create a query that selects the dates to show in the parameter to use as the Available values. Add a column with the MAX date `MAX(Date)OVER(Partition By 1)` to use as the Default Value of the parameter.

Comment: The customer wants to open the link to the report and have the visuals already be displayed with the data for the maximum date without having to select anything in the parameter dropdown.  They only want to use the dropdown for historical dates.  The only solution I have is to just create two reports-one without a parameter that defaults to max date in the sql, and one that is parameter driven, where they can get history